# How can context switch affect the modification of a variable?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, synchronization, context-switch

```
float myTotalAmount=0;
void update(float amt){
    myTotalAmount+= amt;
}
```

task A call `update(10)`;

task B call `update(5);`

How can race condition affect the result of `myTotalAmount` ?

**Task B** is able to call update method because context switch happened due to some reason before **Task A** finished ?

Over all i am trying to understand `race condition`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int myTotalAmount = 0`

**Task A**

`Updata(10);`

**Task B**

`Updata(5)`

---

`myTotalAmount+= amt;` is not an atomic operation. In the sense that this line will be translated to multiple machine commands.

That being said, Task A will save the value of `myTotalAmount` in a register, that value will be 0. If a context switch happends now and `Task B` starts running, it will modify `myTotalAmount` to be 5. Now the OS decides to run `Task A` again.
Even though the value of `myTotalAmount` is now `5`, we've already extracted the value and saved it in a register and it was `0`. The execution of will continue from that point where `myTotalAmount` was `0`. Now `myTotalAmount` will get assigned `0+10` and it will be `10` instead of `15`.

To fix this, you can deploy some synchronization to prevent race condition. You can use lock.

Comment: hi @Tony Tannousi f we use a lock, for example, a mutex (for critical section), even if there is a context switch there will be no danger that a thread will modify the same variable as the newly paused thread because the lock will prevent it, right?